# How to double buffer a RichTextBox in c#?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

Probably not double buffering but I'm trying to make a highlighter (pure amusement) using a RichTextBox. The problem I have is that, when there are a lot of highlighted words, programmer-made flickering appear and even see the textbox scroll.

I don't think that RichTextBox has DoubleBuffered property, and even if it had, it wouldn't word, the flickering is my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int pos = myTextBox.SelectionStart;
RichTextBox buffer = new RichTextBox();
buffer.Rtf = myRichTextBox.Rtf;

//Do whatever you wanna do in buffer


myTextBox.Rtf = buffer.Rtf;
myTextBox.SelectionStart = pos;
myTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
```

Tho, I still have a problem because, no matter what I do, myTextBox.ZoomFactor seems to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Just use LockWindowUpdate on your RichTextBox before changing the color.

Comment: You don't want to use `LockWindowUpdate`. You want to use `SetWindowRedraw`. LockWindowUpdate is not intended for that purpose. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/06/10/152612.aspx)